# COUNTIF cells on a range that differ from those of another range based on a formula

Tags: excel-formula, countif

[image: Golf scorecard]

What I'm trying to achieve is to count the number of cells on a range that differ from cells on another range by a given difference.

In the example: how many double bogeys (none), bogeys (1), pars (2) and birdies (1) there are in a scorecard. For counting, say, Bogeys, this would obviously work, but it's a ridiculous formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B10;B9+1)+COUNTIF(C10;C9+1)+COUNTIF(D10;D9+1)+COUNTIF(E10;E9+1)
```

I've tried many combinations of COUNTIF, COUNTIFS, MATCH... functions, but all return syntax errors.

Help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$10:$E$10-$B$9:$E$9=3-ROW(A1)))
```

[image]
The `3-ROW(A1)` creates the sequence `2,1,0,-1` when dragged down.

Comment: Did not work, but I used your formula to make it work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($R$20:$Z$20-$R$6:$Z$6=-1)) will return the number of berdies
```

Comment: @CarlosTicó - sorry I got it mixed up, should have been `3 - ROW(A1)`.